# Elasticsearch query with date not working

Tags: elasticsearch

When i query to find today's birthday using elasticsearch, it doesn't show any result

```
http://localhost:7272/test/contacts/_search?q=(bdaydate:1991-12-29)
```

But the same works fine when using the below

```
http://localhost:7272/test/contacts/_search?q=(bdaydate:1991-12-29T09:26:29.014Z)
```

I want to query with date alone (without timestamp) and find the birthday contacts whose bdaydate is equal to `1991-12-29`

Help me to achieve this.

Comment: Since you're only interested in the date, take a look at defining the [date format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) in your mapping.

Comment: Thank you @Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

`http://localhost:7272/test/contacts/_search?q=(bdaydate:[1991-12-29 TO 1991-12-29])`

Information found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_ranges)

> Ranges can be specified for date, numeric or string fields. Inclusive ranges are specified with square brackets [min TO max] and exclusive ranges with curly brackets {min TO max}.